# How to smooth out jaggy lines with AviSynth?

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, x264, avisynth, megui

I have a quite crappy quality video in *480p*, I then transcode it with AviSynth and MeGUI. I use a few scripts to enhance the quality, as well as upscaling the video to *720p*. As you can see in the image below, the output has a major improvement in quality. I really think it still can be improved, but I can't smooth out the jaggy lines with my script. Does anyone know how to do it? Or recommend some plugins for AviSynth that specially get rid of those jaggy lines.

[image]

***[Open the image in new tab, and zoom in to see details of the image.]***